# Convergence of series with terms having cosine function

Tags: real-analysis

> Is the series with general term
>   $$U_n =\frac{\cos^nn\pi/8}n$$ convergent or divergent?

My observations are :
Series is not oscillating series.Some terms of the series are positive and some are negative but not alternatively.
I couldn't solve this by Lebnitz test.
I tried to compare this series with the series with general term $\frac1n$.But I couldn't conclude anything.
How can we solve this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

By $\cos(\pi n)/8$ do you mean $\cos^n(\frac{\pi n}{8})$ or $\frac{\cos^n(\pi n)}{8}$? I assume you mean the latter?

The series formed from the sequence $U_n$ is actually a convergent series. First, observe that $\cos^n(\pi n)$ is $-1$ for odd natural numbers $n$, and $1$ for the evens. Let's write out the first few terms of the sequence. We have that:
\begin{align*}
U_1 = -\frac{8}{1}\\\\
U_2 = \frac{8}{2}\\\\
U_3 = -\frac{8}{3}.\\\\
\end{align*}

Factoring out the $8$, we may thus rewrite our series as;
\begin{align*}
8 \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n}
\end{align*}
which is a form of the alternating harmonic sequence (which converges). Therefore, your original sum converges. Hope this helps.

Comment: By Cos Πn/8,I mean cos (nΠ/8)

Comment: But in this answer U1=-1/8,isn't?